# Deriving Flux by Fick's Law with weighted Random Walk

Tags: diffusion

Fick's first law of diffusion, $J=-D\nabla \phi$, is nicely derived from a random walk on wikipedia's page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion

The physical argument is that if you have $\Delta x$ regions, half of the particles diffuse left and half right, aka a random walk, the rest of the derivation falls out.

I am interested in the case of a slight deviation in left and right going particle motion at each $\Delta t$ timestep.  Perhaps a temperature gradient for instance. Lets say the leftgoing probability is now $1/2+\delta$,  and rightgoing is $1/2-\delta$.  I have been able to nearly derive through this expression, lumping the $\delta$ terms as an added term, arriving at:

$J=-D[\nabla \phi+2\delta \times\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (\frac{\phi(x+\Delta x,t)}{\Delta x}+\frac{\phi(x,t)}{\Delta x})]$

If I ignore the value of the limit for a minute, this intuitively makes sense, I would expect more flow in the direction of higher weight...However taking the limit further is beyond me, certainly not a simple derivative expression.  If I Taylor expand and drop higher order $\Delta x$ terms I cannot remove the $1/(\Delta x)$ terms.  Am I approaching this problem correctly or missing something in the derivation?  I imagine the idea of 1D diffusion with a temperature gradient has already been tackled (Onsager relations?)

Comment: Carefully check the sign within the limit.

Comment: I have... $(1/2+\delta)N(x)-(1/2-\delta)N(x+\Delta x)$, the signs on the $\delta$ terms are always the same...